# Rails console でモデルのインスタンスの表示時に特定のカラムを非表示(省略表示)にする

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

`serialize`を使って`Array`を保存してるモデルがあるのですが、Array部分がやや大きく、Rails Consoleで表示すると他のカラムがすぐに流れていってしまい非常に扱いづらくなってしまいました。

```
foo = Foo.fisrt
#<Foo:0x00000000000> {
    :id => 1,
    # ここの表示がすぐに流れてしまい使いづらい。
    :serialized_column => [
      # ターミナル数画面程度の量がある配列
    ]
}
```

状態としてはこのような感じです。

この`serialized_column`を明示的に呼び出さない限りは表示させないようにしたかったのですが何か方法はありますか？

`inspect`を上書きすればよいかと思ったのですが別の方法で呼ばれてるようでオーバーライドしても変化はありませんでした。
また上書きするにしても開発環境にしか影響をあたえないようにしておきたいです。

Answer (score 0):

Hirbというgemはレコード出力を整形できます。

serialized_columnのようなデータが手元にないので、未確認ですが、調整できるかもしれません。

https://github.com/cldwalker/hirb